# SQL add SUM by year to next year

Tags: sql-server

i have a table with col1, col2, year. I would like to create a query like:

```
SELECT
SUM(col1-col2)
FROM table1
WHERE year = '2015'
```

and query result set to new column 'col3' for year =2016,next would be(for 2017):

```
SELECT
SUM(col1-col2)
FROM table1
WHERE year = '2015' AND year = '2016'
```

, stopped when year is max.

Comment: What do you mean "new column col3"?    What does your desired result look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `group by` case.

```
select year, sum(col1-col2) as col3
from table1
group by year
```

If you wanted to limit this to specific years you can use a `where` clause, but you wanted an `or` not an `and` (a row cannot have year=2015 AND year=2016)

```
select year, sum(col1-col2) as col3
from table1
where year='2015' or year = '2016'
group by year
```

Comment: Dynamically ? i want to set my result to next year, etc, etc

Comment: @DejmienF I have no idea what that comment meant in the context of this answer

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure I will do it with GROUP clause that's the way my mind works...
but here if they ask you on the interview as well can you do it with no GROUP CLAUSE?

as well most of the time it is datetime column you should have YEAR function

```
select distinct YEAR(datecolumn) as 'year', sum(col1-col2) OVER() as col3
from table1

select distinct YEAR(datecolumn) as 'year', sum(col1-col2) OVER() as col3
from table1
where YEAR(datecolumn) in ('2015', '2016')
```

Answer (score -2):

Dynamically ?
 i want to set my result to next year, etc, etc

Comment: This is not an answer. The answer box is purely for providing answers. If you wanted to edit your question use the `edit` link.